# Rails - How to use accepts nested attributes within .new (without saving to the database)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to build up a model without storing it in the database, but with accepting nested attributes. It appears that passing parameters with nested attributes to .new does not accept them, and just creates a new model, without any of the passed associations.

Is there a way to have .new accept nested attributes, or another method I can use to accomplish this?

Thanks!

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your requirements correctly. Do you want to use `accepts_nested_attirbutes_for` in a pure Ruby class that does not inherit from `ActiveRecord`? Then the answer is no because `accepts_nested_attributes_for` is implemented in `ActiveRecord::NestedAttributes`. If you want similar behavior in a pure Ruby object then you need to implement it on your own.

Comment: Thanks! Sorry for not being clear. This is an active record model. Basically I am creating a wizard, and I wish to store each step in cache, and not in the database. So I need to instantiate the model (with the data from a nested form), but not have it saved to the database. I can then store it in the cache and move on to the next step.

Comment: Show your code.

Comment: I am not great with multi steps processes. But how do you want to carry on with the wizard without creating records ? Your will have to forward a lot of nested data from a step to another using hidden fields. Also you cannot validate your data until the last wizard step..  An easier solution would be to mark your records with state "dirty" or "not final".

Comment: @maxence You're correct that just saving the data in the DB would be a much simpler and more rubust solution but not quite correct when it comes to the other points. Validations will still be runnable (per step validations are pretty easy to acheive with the form objects pattern) - you can also "dry insert" records by using transactions. If you're using a cache mechanism (Redis, memcached, file system) instead of passing the entire state though http parameters you also just need a single hidden input with a cache key.

Comment: There is also a completely different alternative which is just to use a single form and just turn into a "wizard" using CSS/JS. Tons of libs for that.

Comment: I've been using this walkthrough for wizards that go through all of these options: https://jonsully.net/blog/rails-wizards-part-one/ . It's really informative going through the pros and cons of each option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're basing the entire question on a faulty premise.

```ruby
class Company < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :products
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :products
end
```

```ruby
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :company
end
```

```
irb(main):002:0> c = Company.new(name: 'Acme', products_attributes: [ { name: 'Anvil' }])
=> #<Company:0x000056417471c2b0 id: nil, name: "Acme", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
irb(main):003:0> c.products
=> [#<Product:0x0000564174972258 id: nil, name: "Anvil", company_id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>]
```

As you can see here the attributes are very much passed to `.new` - in fact thats exactly what the entire feature is supposed to do so it would be strange otherwise.

So whats actually going wrong? The most likely explaination is that you aren't whitelisting the parameters for the nested records. Make sure that you're using the correct pluralization - the parameter key is `singular_attributes` for `belongs_to` / `has_one` and `plural_attributes` for `has_many`/`has_and_belongs_to_many`.

Comment: This was it. The issue was I had an after initialize method that was overwriting what was being set in the attributes. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: The company_id of c.products is nil